# Java regex to pad the pattern of interest with blanks

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to locate multiple instances of a pattern of interest within a string and then pad it, on both sides, with white spaces.  I tried my hand at some sample code, but it is not giving the result I am looking for.  My sample code follows.

In this example I am trying to pad the pattern `"excerpt":` with blanks on either side i.e. it becomes  `"excerpt":` .

---

```
public class RegexTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "\"date\":1615443360,\"excerpt\":\"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\"";
        System.out.println(str + "\n\n");
        if(str.contains("\"excerpt\":")) {
            str = str.replaceAll("(.)*\"excerpt\":(.)*", "$0" + " " + "$1" + " " + "$2");
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.+)*(\"excerpt\":)(.+)*", "$1" + " " + "$2" + " " + "$3");
```

but of course some simple `replace("XXX", " XXX ")` is a lot easier.

Comment: This substitution returns a blank string for me.

Comment: @Sandeep [here you go](https://onecompiler.com/java/3wrb9gv4c)

Answer (score 0):

Your input text seriously looks like a JSON fragment, and, if so, you should probably be working with the original JSON using a library like Gson.  That being said, you could try this replacement:

```java
String str = "\"date\":1615443360,\"excerpt\":\"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\"";
System.out.println(str);
str = str.replace("\"excerpt\"", " \"excerpt\" ");
System.out.println(str);
```

This prints:

```
"date":1615443360,"excerpt":"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
"date":1615443360, "excerpt" :"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```